# Simple Touch Controls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been testing my game on my computer, with the left & right arrows, but I want to switch it to a touch control.

I've looked into some tutorials, but some say I need to purchase an asset from the store or it doesn't really fit my needs.

I just need some guidance for the best direction I should take :)

This is my code for my controls right now, I was wondering if I can use 2 buttons since I only need to move left and right?

```
 void Update()
 {
     transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x < maxWidth)
     {
         targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x + Xincrement, transform.position.y);
         transform.position = targetPos;
     }
     else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x > minWidth)
     {
         targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x - Xincrement, transform.position.y);
         transform.position = targetPos;
     }
 }
```

Comment: There are some standard asset touch controls already. Just import the standard assets package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for touching half right/left screen to move

```
 void Update () { 
     transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);  
     // Detect touch event         
     Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
     if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
     {
        if (touch.position.x > (Screen.width / 2))
        {
            if (transform.position.x < maxWidth)
            {
                targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x + Xincrement, transform.position.y);
                transform.position = targetPos;
            }
        } 
        else {
            if (transform.position.x > minWidth)
            {
                targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x - Xincrement, transform.position.y);
     transform.position = targetPos;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: AHHHHHH THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I'm just learning and the documentation & tutorials online were so complicated on touch controls...

Answer (score 0):

Use code that gets the position of the mouse when tapped, and check if its on the right or left part of the screen